# Implementing JTable update

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have the following code for creating a JTable

```
public void tableTeam()
{
    rl.readRunners();
    String[] sampleHeaders = {"Athlete ID", "Team"};

    JTable myTable = new JTable(rl.teamTableData,sampleHeaders);

    myTable.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
    myTable.setRowHeight(20);
    ///////////////
    sorter = new TableRowSorter(myTable.getModel());
    List sortKeys = new ArrayList();
    sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(1, SortOrder.DESCENDING));
    sorter.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
    sorter.setRowFilter
    (
        new RowFilter<TableModel, Integer>()
            {
            @Override
            public boolean include(RowFilter.Entry<? extends TableModel, ? extends Integer> entry) 
                {
                    boolean included = true;
                    Object cellValue = entry.getModel().getValueAt(entry.getIdentifier(), 0);
                    if (cellValue == null || cellValue.toString().trim().isEmpty())
                    {
                        included = false;
                    }
                    return included;
                }
            }
    );
    myTable.setRowSorter(sorter);
    ///////////////

    teamScrollTable = new JScrollPane(myTable);
    teamScrollTable.setSize(500,300);
    teamScrollTable.setLocation(50,100); 
    System.out.println("Creating team table");



    teamPanel.add(teamScrollTable);
}
```

And then I have this code to update the table.

```
public void RefreshTeam()
{
    teamPanel.remove(teamScrollTable);

    rl.readRunners();
    String[] sampleHeaders = {"Athlete ID", "Team"};

    JTable myTable = new JTable(rl.teamTableData,sampleHeaders);

    myTable.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
    myTable.setRowHeight(20);
    ///////////////
    sorter = new TableRowSorter(myTable.getModel());
    List sortKeys = new ArrayList();
    sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(1, SortOrder.DESCENDING));
    sorter.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
    sorter.setRowFilter
    (
        new RowFilter<TableModel, Integer>()
            {
            @Override
            public boolean include(RowFilter.Entry<? extends TableModel, ? extends Integer> entry) 
                {
                    boolean included = true;
                    Object cellValue = entry.getModel().getValueAt(entry.getIdentifier(), 0);
                    if (cellValue == null || cellValue.toString().trim().isEmpty())
                    {
                        included = false;
                    }
                    return included;
                }
            }
    );
    myTable.setRowSorter(sorter);

    teamScrollTable = new JScrollPane(myTable);
    teamScrollTable.setSize(500,300);
    teamScrollTable.setLocation(50,100); 
    System.out.println("Changing team table");

    teamPanel.add(teamScrollTable);
}
```

This code is activated when a button is clicked on the program. However unlike my expectations this does not update the table. I did some research and found this line of code `fireTableCellUpdated()`. Although I am unable to implement this into my code so that it updates the table since I do not know how. I would greatly appreciate someone helping me implement this code or showing me a better way to do what I want.

Comment: I am aware of the [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) however I tried implementing this code but it was unsuccessful

Answer (score 2):

In order to update the table you can use the following:

```
myTable.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(rl.teamTableData,sampleHeaders));
```

Comment: Yes, resetting the model will work and this approach should be used instead of creating all new components (+1). You may lose the sorter, but the data in the table will display properly assuming you have updated the "rl.teamTableData" properly.

Answer (score 0):

The refreshTeam method (note java methods should begin with lowercase) is not updating the JTable, it is creating a new table entirely, and then trying to add these Components to (what I presume is) an already visible UI. The UI is unaware of this, so after adding/removing Components you should call...

```
revalidate();
repaint();
```

...on the components. There are alternatives to this approach - you can change the model rather than recreating the table. You can do so by implementing your own [AbstractTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) (you can then call the fireTableDataChanged that you refer to on the instance to update listeners that the data has changed).